# Using Collectors.toMap how to convert the map values

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a `Map<String, List<StartingMaterial>>` 
I want to convert the Object in the List to another Object.
ie. `Map<String, List<StartingMaterialResponse>>`

Can I do this using java stream Collectors.toMap()?

I tried something like the below code.

```
Map<String, List<StartingMaterial>>  startingMaterialMap = xxxx;

startingMaterialMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap( Map.Entry::getKey, Function.identity(), (k, v) -> convertStartingMaterialToDto(v.getValue())));
```

And my conversion code to change the Object is like below,

```
private StartingMaterialResponse convertStartingMaterialToDto(StartingMaterial sm) {

    final StartingMaterialMatrix smm = sm.getStartingMaterialMatrix();
    final StartingMaterial blending1Matrix = smm.getBlending1Matrix();
    final StartingMaterial blending2Matrix = smm.getBlending2Matrix();

    return new StartingMaterialResponse(
            sm.getId(),
            sm.getComponent().getCasNumber(),
            sm.getDescription(),
            sm.getPriority(),
            String.join(" : ",
                    Arrays.asList(smm.getCarryInMatrix().getComponent().getMolecularFormula(),
                            blending1Matrix != null ? blending1Matrix.getComponent().getMolecularFormula() : "",
                            blending2Matrix != null ? blending2Matrix.getComponent().getMolecularFormula() : ""
                    ).stream().distinct().filter(m -> !m.equals("")).collect(Collectors.toList())),
            smm.getFamily(),
            smm.getSplitGroup());
}
```

Comment: If by any chance `Map<String, List<StartingMaterial>>` was formed of `groupingBy`, you could have provided [`Collectors.mapping` as a downstream collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) upfront. Of course, that's when you don't want to make use of `Map<String, List<StartingMaterial>>` on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the toMap collector since your source is a map. However you have to iterate over all the values and convert each of them into the DTO format inside the valueMapper.

```
Map<String, List<StartingMaterialResponse>> result = startingMaterialMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .map(s -> convertStartingMaterialToDto(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to do :

```
startingMaterialMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(this::convertStartingMaterialToDto)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to this problem :

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> deposits = new HashMap<>();

    deposits.put("first", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    deposits.forEach((depositName, products) -> {
        products.stream()
                .map(myIntegerProduct -> myIntegerProduct.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
```

The above example convert the `List<Integer>` to a list of Strings.
In your example, instead of `myIntegerProduct.toString()` is the `convertStartingMaterialToDto` method.

The `forEach` method iterates through every ***Key-Value*** pair in the map and you set some names for the key and the value parameters to be more specific and keep an understandable code for everyone who reads it. In my example : `forEach( (depositName, products)) ->` the **depositName** is the Key ( in my case a String ) and the **products** is the Value of the key ( in my case is a List of integers ).

Finally you iterate through the list too and `map` every item to a new type

`products.stream()
         .map(myIntegerProduct -> myIntegerProduct.toString())`